# ruby split a text file with regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

Is it possible to split this text file into fields with tab delimiters? The file has over 5,000 lines and the last 3 data fields may not be present. Asco may also be only 2 or 3 digits.

```
qualification_code name level_of_education field_of_education asco anzsco
ACM10110 Certificate I in Animal Studies      524 0611 6399-15 361199
ACM20110 Certificate II in Animal Studies     521 0611 6399-15 361199
ACM30110 Certificate III in Animal Studies    514 0611 6399-15 361199
ACM30210 Certificate III in Animal Technology 514 0611 6399-15 361199
ACM30310 Certificate III in Captive Animals   514 0611 6399-15 361199
CHC41012 Certificate IV in Community Services Advocacy 511 0905 2512-13 411711
```

Comment: Is it possible? Probably. You should try.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. Any help appreciated greatly.

Comment: Are you sure the file does not contain delimiters? Tabs for example may not be visible by just looking directly at the file unless you examine it more closely.

Comment: For example looking at the text you pasted here there is a tab character between `name` and `level_of_education` in the data.

Comment: Not sure how to check that, here isa  link to the files. This one is units of competency. http://www.ncver.edu.au/publications/1452.html

Comment: Thanks Casper, I will try to split it based on tabs. Just need to figure out how to parse this into a database (pg).

Comment: Yep. It says so on the page: *"Files are supplied as tab delimited text format files and should be saved to your computer before opening."*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require "csv"

CSV.foreach("test.dat", :col_sep => "\t", :headers => true) do |row| 
  puts row[0]
  # or puts row
  # or whatever processing you want here
end
```

Because the OP brought up Postgres as an import target in comments `pgadmin` (free/OSS) includes an [import tool as of pgadmin version 1.16](http://www.pgadmin.org/visualtour16.php). This applies only if there's no reason to perform the task programmatically (i.e. include new data as its updated).

Comment: `:col_sep => '\t'` should be `:col_sep => "\t"`. `'\t'` is a literal backslash-T, not a tab. Otherwise this is the right way to handle the problem.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I get for thinking I verified the answer in `irb` correctly - updated.

Answer (score 1):

The download page confirms the data is tab delimited:

> *Files are supplied as tab delimited text format files and should be saved to your computer before opening.*

You can use something like [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) to do the task for you.

You can look in the examples folder for some sample code on how to use it:
https://github.com/JEG2/faster_csv/tree/master/examples

Comment: FasterCSV is now incorporated into Ruby as CSV.